# Position a node a certain distance away from another node at a certain angle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

Like the title says, is it possible to position a node a certain distance away from another node at a certain angle from that node?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, TikZ can use polar coordinates. Not sure exactly what is the best way of defining the second node, here is one way.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {A};
  \path (A) ++(30:2) node (B) [draw,fill=blue!20] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In `(30:2)` 30 is the angle, 2 the distance. 0° is to the right, positive direction is counterclockwise, so node `B` will be above and to the right of `A`.

Comment: Gnashing teeth - just beat me to it...

Comment: Is it possible to use the `\node` command instead of `\path`? Or at least include a style in `\path`?

Comment: @gablin: I'm no expert, but I wasn't able to think of a way to do it with `\node`. But you can still do stuff like `\path (A) ++(30:2) node (B) [draw,fill=blue!20] {B};` to style the node, if that was what you wanted.

Comment: @Torbjorn T: Yup, that's what I wanted. Thanks! =)

Comment: No need to split it in two lines. `\node {A} ++(30:2) node {B};`

Answer (score 15):

TikZ allows you to specify positions and vectors in polar coordinates. Here's an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (a) {A node};
\node at (120:1cm) (b) {B node};
\path (a) ++(-45:2cm) node (c) {C node}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can shift node position B regarding to another node A from an angle and a radius in the following way:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (A) {A};
   \node (B) at ([shift=({240:1 cm})]A) {B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Estrada:  I guess that your way is the simplest one

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to define a node using node coordinate system:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) {A};
\node[draw,circle] 
    (node cs:name=B) at ($(node cs:name=A)+(30:2)$) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```